# How te select nth (every) subitem under unordered list?

Tags: html, css

```css
.left li i { border: 1px solid red; }
.left li:nth-child(3) > i{ border: 1px solid black; }
```

```html
<div class="left">
  <ul>
    <li>some data<i>icon</i></li>
    <li>some data<i>icon</i></li>
    <li>some data<i>icon</i></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Now I want to apply specific rule to every **i** item, like for example border color, but my selector won't work. First selector works fine, but second not, I can't target for example first item, and then apply different border color, and then apply different border color for second, third or fourth item, or in that case `<i>` tag.

Comment: Your `ul` element doesn't have a class of "left". `<ul class="left">...</ul>`. Adding that class in fixes the problem. I've voted to close this as it's nothing but a typographical error.

Comment: you dont have any class in `ul`

Comment: @AlanKis I've converted your code into a Stack Overflow code snippet. When hitting "Run code snippet", your code appears to work correctly.

Comment: @JamesDonnelly, I can see that, weird. I'll edit my question with full markup.

Answer (score 0):

see the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zj9v81t7/21/

```
<ul>
<li>some data<i>icon</i></li>
<li>some data<i>icon</i></li>
<li>some data<i>icon</i></li>
</ul>
css
    ul li i { border: 1px solid red; }
    ul li:nth-child(2) > i{ border: 1px solid blue; }
ul li:nth-child(3) > i{ border: 1px solid black; }
```